# .jar file plays sound when run on console, but not when double clicked

Tags: java, audio, jar, console

I'm sorry if it's a dumb question, but I'm pretty new to this and I couldn't find anything on the web for my problem.

The thing is, when I run my Chicken.jar from the console with **java -jar Chicken.jar** it works just fine. All images are shown and the sound is played. But when i try to run it by double-clicking from the directory, the game starts up normally, all the images are shown but the sound is missing. 
I tried to reinstall the jdk already but it didn't help.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: without seeing any config/code/... all we can do is guess

Comment: sorry! what is that and how do i post it?

Comment: You may have to head over to a Linux help area, where they can help you figure out what exact java.exe is being invoked in the two different startup methods (maybe two different versions involved). Then head back here with that info and we can try and troubleshoot further. If sound doesn't play, bear in mind also that the cause could be related to any step along the chain--i.e., it could be an intermediate step of some sort. Useful: make a very simple sound-generating java program and see if it exhibits the same problem (e.g., single button that executes Clip command).

Answer (score 0):

It may be a problem with permissions. Maybe you start it in the console using administrator permissions and by double clicking with user permissions.

Comment: how do you start it by double clicking with administrator permissions on a linux?

Comment: Which Linux exactly?

Comment: Linux Mint 18.3

Comment: Hmm... I don't know exactly. Maybe you can add a Start.sh containing "sudo java..." and executing this one instead?